# INNER JOIN con 3 Tablas

Tags: mysql

necesito hacer un INNER Join con 3 tablas relacionadas entre sí

Os pongo en situación...

Tabla 1: **entradas_historia**

- *historia_paciente* - **Clave Foránea**
- *fecha*
- *hora*

Tabla 2: **pacientes**

- *historia* - **Clave Foránea de historia_paciente**
- *fecha_alta*
- *terapeuta1* - **Clave Foránea de id en personal**
- *terapeuta2* - **Clave Foránea de id en personal**
- *terapeuta3* - **Clave Foránea de id en personal**

Tabla 3: **personal**

- *id* - **Clave Foránea de terapeuta**
- *nombre*
- *apellidos*

Yo quiero sacar el nombre del terapeuta1, terapeuta2 y terapeuta3. Actualmente ya saco todos los demás datos, pero en terapeuta1, terapeuta2 y terapeuta3 saco las id's y yo quiero sacar el nombre de cada terapeuta. Mi código actualmente está así

```
SELECT h.*, p.nombre, p.apellidos, p.fecha_alta, p.terapeuta1, p.terapeuta2, p.terapeuta3 FROM entradas_historia h INNER JOIN pacientes p ON historia_paciente = historia
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la respuesta de Valentín, pude de terminar de desarrollar la solución

```
SELECT h.*,
    pac.nombre, 
    pac.apellidos, 
    pac.poblacion, 
    pac.tlfn1,
    pac.estado_civil,
    pe1.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta1,
    pe2.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta2, 
    pe3.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta3

    FROM entradas_historia h INNER JOIN pacientes pac
    ON h.historia_paciente = pac.historia
    INNER JOIN personal pe1 ON pac.terapeuta1 = pe1.id
    INNER JOIN personal pe2 ON pac.terapeuta2 = pe2.id
    INNER JOIN personal pe3 ON pac.terapeuta3 = pe3.id
```